# SwingWorker worker with SerialEvent( apped to JTextField )

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I am trying to make a serialmonitor in java and I am stuck. I try to apped a text(serial input) to a JTextArea. I tryed using SwingWorker and I had some succes but not good enoughf.

I have an event(SerialEventListener) wich reads the input data.
In this event I am trying to append the incoming data to a JTextArea wich is declared in another class and the append method wont work. I've read that it should not work and that I need to use SwingWorker and I did. The problem is that the executing process of SwingWorker starts only if I give command to execute in a button event.
In conclusion I want to execute the swingworker rutine as I get data from serial port.
Example: serialevent(a data in arrived) -> appedrutine(swingworker) -> finish
This is my code:

The class that holds my graphic components:
centerPanel

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;


public class centerPanel implements ActionListener{

private JTabbedPane tabbed_pane = new JTabbedPane();
public JPanel tab_source    = new JPanel();
public JPanel tab_graphical = new JPanel();
private updateData updateText_method;
private JTextArea data_content = new JTextArea();
private JButton Freeze, Clear, Reload;

public centerPanel(){

    tabbed_pane.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Data visualization"));

    Freeze = new JButton("Freeze");
    Freeze.addActionListener(this);

    Clear  = new JButton("Clear");
    Clear.addActionListener(this);

    Reload = new JButton("Reload");
    Reload.addActionListener(this);

    BoxLayout box_layout = new BoxLayout(tab_source,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    tab_source.setLayout(box_layout);

    data_content.setEditable(false);
    data_content.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    data_content.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

    tab_source.add(new JScrollPane(data_content));

    JPanel temp_panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    temp_panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Data control"));
    temp_panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(MainFrame.window_width,(int)(MainFrame.window_height*0.07)));
    temp_panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(MainFrame.window_width,  (int)(MainFrame.window_height*0.12)));

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.insets = new Insets(0,8,8,0);

    temp_panel.add(Freeze,c);
    c.gridx = 1;
    temp_panel.add(Clear,c);
    c.gridx = 2;
    temp_panel.add(Reload,c);

    tab_source.add(temp_panel,BorderLayout.LINE_END);

    tabbed_pane.addTab("Text mode",tab_source);
    tabbed_pane.addTab("Graphic mode",tab_graphical);

}

public JTabbedPane getTabs(){

    return tabbed_pane;

}

public void updateData(){

     updateText_method = new updateData(data_content);
     updateText_method.execute();

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    if(event.getSource() == Clear){

        updateData();

    }

}

}
```

Here is my serialMonitor class(reads from serial port)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier;
import javax.comm.SerialPort;
import javax.comm.SerialPortEvent;
import javax.comm.SerialPortEventListener;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class serialMonitor implements SerialPortEventListener {

private static CommPortIdentifier pid;
private static SerialPort port;
private InputStream inputstream;
private static OutputStream outputstream;
public static int data ;


public void openPort(String portname, int baudrate){

    System.out.println(new String(""+ baudrate + "xx" +portname));
    try {

         pid=CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portname);

         port=(SerialPort)pid.open("owner",2000);
         port.setSerialPortParams(baudrate, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
         outputstream=port.getOutputStream();
         inputstream=port.getInputStream();
         port.addEventListener(this);
         port.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new Frame("Info"), "Connection problems!");} 


}

public void closePort(String mesaj){

    try{
         port.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new Frame("Info"), "Connection problems!");}

}

@Override
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent sE) {

    try {

        inputstream=port.getInputStream();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new Frame("Info"), "Connection problem! Cant read data from quadcopter");
    }

    if (sE.getEventType()==SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {

        try
        {
            while ( ( data = inputstream.read()) > -1 ){

              System.out.println(data);

              { 
                 //This is where i want to make the update
                 //something like centerPanel_obj.updataData()
                 //
              } 

            }

        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

    }



}





}
```

Here is my updataData class(where SwingWorker is)

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class updateData extends SwingWorker<Integer, String> {

private final JTextArea messagesTextArea;

public updateData(final JTextArea messagesTextArea) {
this.messagesTextArea = messagesTextArea;
}

 @Override
 protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {

int i;
  for ( i = 0; i<50; i++) 
    publish(new String(""+i));

 return 1;

}

@Override
protected void process(final List<String> chunks) {

for (final String string : chunks) {
  messagesTextArea.append(string);
  messagesTextArea.append("\n");
  }
}
```

}

Note: I will accept every critic regarding my code and my description so I if you have some...dont be shy. Thank you!

Comment: first critic, follow java naming code conventions

Comment: Thank you. I just printed Java Code Conventions (September 12,1997).  Awaiting for the second critic.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot you could work on.  But I'll give you the basics.

Everything an end user does in your application runs on a single thread - the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) -  unless you intentionally put it on a different thread.  So if the user clicks a button, and you start doing something that takes a while, the UI will freeze until you're done.

The simple way of getting around that is to start a new Thread that does your work.

But... you also have to consider *any* UI updates have to be done on the EDT as well (Oh, nos!).  [SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable doRun)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) was created so that you can put a process in the queue to run on the EDT.

[SwingWorker's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) job is to make this whole rigamarole easier.  It provides an interface for 1) Executing code in a thread off of the EDT and 2) Executing code in a thread in the EDT (after the first thread finishes)

---

Now, here are a few things that are unclear from your question:

- `serialMonitor` isn't even a part of the code - I'm not sure what you want to do with it
- It's unclear whether you want a user action to trigger an update of the UI or if an event (communication) on the serial port should trigger the update

If your `SerialMonitor` is already executing on its own thread (not on the EDT), which I assume it has to be, then whenever you need to update the UI, you just wrap the call like this:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Insert your code to update UI here
    }
});
```

Granted you will need to give `SerialMonitor` access to the UI piece to update.

Comment: First thank you for your comment. The main ideea is that when a user presses "open" button...the serial port is opened and if data is incoming from serial port ...it will start update the textarea. So what I am trying to do is to update the textfield only when I get something from the serial. I figured that will be ok to update the UI by running a thread in serialMonitor.

Comment: Oh oh...EVRIKA. The main problem was that I instanciate my JTextArea outside of my constructor and the bigger mistake was that it wasn't static . And indeed...inserting the appeding operation into EDT queue by using invokeLater Thread helped a lot when getting a lot of data from a serial port. Thank you very much.